# grouping calculation, with several unique constraints

Tags: r

I'm looking to go from here:

```
#Create data frame
id = c(1,1,1,8,2,2,2,3,3,9,4,5,6,6,7) 
name = c("tim","tim","tim","bill","jack","jack","jack","matt","matt","jen","dave","chris","kate","kate","brad") 
value_1 = c(50,50,50,55,50,0,50,88,88,90,75,90,110,110,65) 
df =data.frame(id,name,value_1)
```

To here:

```
#Create data frame
id = c(1,1,1,8,2,2,2,3,3,9,4,5,6,6,7) 
name = c("tim","tim","tim","bill","jack","jack","jack","matt","matt","jen","dave","chris","kate","kate","brad") 
value_1 = c(50,0,0,55,50,0,0,88,0,90,75,90,110,0,65) 
final_df =data.frame(id,name,value_1)
```

I need to substitute dups in the value_1 column with a zero, only when the following conditions are satisfied: if unique id count is greater than 1, AND name is the same, AND value_1 is the same, then replace all values with zero except one value.  I hope this makes sense.  I'm having troubling figuring this out, without losing any observations.  I need to keep all observations, cause there are other variables in this data set that I cannot remove.

Thanks for your help R community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `duplicated` to assign the values of duplicate elements in 'value_1' to 0

```
df$value_1[duplicated(df)] <- 0
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, .I[seq_len(.N) != 1], .(id, name)]$V1
df[i1, value_1 := 0]
df
#    id  name value_1
# 1:  1   tim      50
# 2:  1   tim       0
# 3:  1   tim       0
# 4:  8  bill      55
# 5:  2  jack      50
# 6:  2  jack       0
# 7:  2  jack       0
# 8:  3  matt      88
# 9:  3  matt       0
#10:  9   jen      90
#11:  4  dave      75
#12:  5 chris      90
#13:  6  kate     110
#14:  6  kate       0
#15:  7  brad      65
```

---

Or with `dplyr` with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id, name) %>%
   mutate(value_1 = case_when(row_number() > 1 ~ 0, TRUE ~ value_1))
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups: id, name [9]
#      id name   value_1
#   <dbl> <fctr>   <dbl>
# 1  1.00 tim       50.0
# 2  1.00 tim        0  
# 3  1.00 tim        0  
# 4  8.00 bill      55.0
# 5  2.00 jack      50.0
# 6  2.00 jack       0  
# 7  2.00 jack       0  
# 8  3.00 matt      88.0
# 9  3.00 matt       0  
#10  9.00 jen       90.0
#11  4.00 dave      75.0
#12  5.00 chris     90.0
#13  6.00 kate     110  
#14  6.00 kate       0  
#15  7.00 brad      65.0
```

Comment: your first solution is so simple and works and makes me stupid for asking the question.  But how does that recognize unique_id and name?

Comment: @DCRubyHound  It  works if we want to filter out the duplicate elements in the dataset `duplicated(df)` and assign the 'value_1' corresponding to it to 0

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ave` grouped by `id` and `name` and replace all the values except the first one for that group.

```
df$value_1 <- with(df, ave(value_1, id, name, FUN = function(x) 
                    replace(x, seq_along(x) != 1, 0)))


df
#   id  name value_1
#1   1   tim      50
#2   1   tim       0
#3   1   tim       0
#4   8  bill      55
#5   2  jack      50
#6   2  jack       0
#7   2  jack       0
#8   3  matt      88
#9   3  matt       0
#10  9   jen      90
#11  4  dave      75
#12  5 chris      90
#13  6  kate     110
#14  6  kate       0
#15  7  brad      65
```

---

We can do similar with `dplyr` as well

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id, name) %>%
   mutate(value_1 = replace(value_1, seq_along(value_1) != 1, 0))
```